# Erro ao criar pasta no PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

Estou com problemas para usar o [`mkdir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mkdir.php) dentro da minha *vps* no **Digital Ocean**. Instalei o **LAMP** e fiz todas as configurações devidas para rodar o meu sistema. Porém, na área de criação de pastas, ele não está funcionando. Segue o código:

```
$pasta = 'teste';
$path = '/var/www/meusite.com.br/' . $pasta;

if (!mkdir($path, 0755, true)) 
{
    echo('Não foi possível criar a pasta');
}
else
{
    echo('Pasta criada com sucesso!');
}
```

O retorno sempre é `FALSE`.

Existe alguma variável de erro neste caso que eu saiba identificar porque ele não consegue criar?

Alguma ideia do que possa ser? Estou usando a versão 7.2 do PHP.

Comment: A pasta `/var/www/meusite.com.br/` tem permissão de escrita para o grupo **www-data**?

Comment: @ErlonCharles Realmente era permissão. A permissão só estava no usuário e não no www-data. Obrigado pela ajuda amigo!

Comment: Vou inserir uma resposta apenas para registro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que o **php** possa executar ações de criação de arquivos e diretórios, sendo assim verifique se sua pasta `/var/www/meusite.com.br/` tem permissão para o grupo **www-data**.

Defina essa permissão com o comando:

```
sudo chown -R {usuario_logado}:www-data /var/www/meusite.com.br/
```

Comment: Complementando: no Laravel, eu utilizo o `sudo chmod -Rf 777 /var/www/meusite.com.br/` e funciona também quando tenho problemas relacionados a permissão.

Comment: @CypherPotato **777** você está dando permissão pra qualquer usuário fazer qualquer coisa, o que é um exemplo claro de falta de segurança, as pastas deves estar com permissão **755** e os arquivos com permissão **644** e todos com permissão para o grupo **www-data** para que o **php** possa executar ações de criação de pasta e arquivos.